# Exclude objects from all collections/queries unless explicitly asked for

Tags: laravel

I'll have some items in a model's database table that I more often that not won't want to include in queries for that model. So, rather than querying to exclude these items everywhere I call for the model, either directly or via a relationship, it would be nice to tell Laravel 'in one place' to exclude these items from all collections. The criteria for excluding will be a column value.

Perhaps somewhere in the model I can put this criteria?

Ideally the solution will also provide a way to easily explicitly re-include those excluded items in collections, at the point of querying.

Laravel's model scopes are almost there, but I need it the over way around. Perhaps scopes will solve the second part of my quest (in the paragraph above this one).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: Global Scopes. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#global-scopes

I was previously looking at an older Laravel version's doc, which didn't have Global Scopes.